# unclickable button to reset on main page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a button where after the person clicks, it is unclickable but when the person returns to the main page, I want the button to reset and be clickable again. I have managed to do the unclickable part with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        setTimeout(function() { el.removeAttr('disabled'); }, 3000);
    })    
});
```

however, I am unable to do the reset part. Could someone help please?

Comment: Is this happening on a single page app. I mean there is no page reload.

Comment: This is on a website. Its sorta like a quiz microsite.

Comment: Are you sure that you are checking the button after three seconds. Because if you do before that the button it will be still disabled.

Comment: if that is the case, then how should I go about doing it? (even if I have to change the code I gave above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rely on setTimeout to make it enabled. You said that you need to reset it once the user landed on the main page. So, remove the *disabled* attribute in that moment. Pseudo code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    })    
});

var showMainPage = function() {
    el.removeAttr('disabled');
}
```